# How to resize two adjustant partition in Linux

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, gparted, resizing

My hard drive looks like this:
[image]

Now I want to use all the allocated space and double or triple the size of /dev/sdb5 and /dev/sdb6.

But gParted displays warning that if I move the partition then I wont be able to boot the OS.

Can anybody guide me how can I resize these partitions?

Comment: You have - for no reason at all if the drive is GPT - an extended and logical partitions. You need to first expand the extended partition (sdb2) and only then manage the logical partitions inside. Also you can't do it from the running system, you need to boot a live session. To further complicate the process you have a swap partition - also for no reason at all if Ubuntu 18.04 or newer - which is hard to move but can be deleted and recreated at the end of the drive but then you'll have to edit fstab as well. Hope you have backups because what you want to do has an high risk for the data.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia has said it all. Just one additional word of caution: don't hibernate when you boot the live system. Also, if you never hibernate, you can use a [swap file](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq#How_do_I_add_a_swap_file.3F) instead of a swap partition - this is more flexible, as you can easily change the swap size without repartitioning.